# get percetage in one query

Tags: mysql, average

I need something like

```
$query = SELECT COUNT(id) as user_in FROM <table_user> WHERE user= 11;
$query = SELECT COUNT(id) as total FROM <table_user> WHERE 1 ;
$percetage = $user_in / $total * 100;`
```

in one query.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  SUM(IF user=11,1,0)*100/COUNT(*) AS percentage
FROM table_user;
```

Comment: Why does someone always beat me to it on this type of query!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice simple one

```
SELECT SUM(IF(user=11,1,0))/COUNT(id) AS percentageAsDecimal FROM <table_user>
```

Just a warning though, this will error if there are no rows in  as it will be division by 0

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT COUNT(id) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_user) * 100 AS PERCENTAGE
FROM table_user;
WHERE user= 11;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to stay with your approach with 2 initial statements, you can just combine your statements (cartesian product) and do your calculations.

```
SELECT your_calculation FROM select_statement1, select_statement2;
```

In your example this translates to

```
SELECT 100.0*user_in/total FROM
(SELECT COUNT(id) as user_in FROM <table_user> WHERE user= 11),
(SELECT COUNT(id) as total FROM <table_user> WHERE 1);
```

I just tested this with SQLite, by mySQL should be almost the same. In SQLite 100.0 is important in order to avoid an integer division!